# Sorting by inner object field and its performance

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I'm confused that it's hard to make case insensitive sorting work. So I decided to just add second field in addition to main text field in lower case.
I'm using C# driver and in my object model I have something like SortableString which contains original and lowercased string. The question is how mongodb handles sorting over inner object fields? Has it worse performance in comparing with sorting over root-level fields? Any recomendations? (indexes etc.)

Update:

Common object structure

```
"_id" : ObjectId("57ebda72844c4c08d4ad2832"),
"text" : {
    "_l" : "abc",
    "_o" : "Abc"
}
```

Common query structure is used for sorting

```
db.Texts.find({}).sort({"text._l": 1}).skip(100).limit(50)
```

Comment: Hi ahydrax - can you show us the data structure and index you are considering, and typical queries you intend to run against it? Without this detail, it's difficult to be sure whether your proposed data structure is useful or not.

Comment: @VinceBowdren I've updated question with example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work just fine.

MongoDB will happily let you [index an embedded field](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-single/#create-an-index-on-an-embedded-field) like this, and will give the same performance improvements on your queries as from indexing a top-level field.

In your case, you might benefit from indexes such as these:

```
{ "text._l": 1 }
{ "someOtherField" : 1, "text._l": 1 }
```

Your choice of indexes depends on precisely what queries you will be running.

Comment: thanks for answer, I was afraid that it could lead to performance problems